# How do I give name to a mock object?

Tags: python

In `unittest.mock`how can I set `__name__` attribute of a mock function?

I did the following:

```
func = Mock(name="foo")
print(func.__name__)
```

which gives off `AttributeError: __name__`

I also tried to create a custom object with `__name__` attribute and pass it to spec as:

```
class f_mock:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name__ = str(name)

fobj = f_mock("foo")
func = Mock(spec=fobj)
print(func.__name__)
```

which gives off a `TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just set `__name__` directly on the mock?

```
func = Mock()
func.__name__ = 'foo'
print(func.__name__)
```

as Ghassen mentions in his answer, you can also use `configure_mock`, which for all intents and purposes achieves the same thing, but might be preferable if you want to bulk configure multiple properties and/or attributes of your mock instance, as you can put everything in a dictionary, and unpack it to function parameters. For example,

```
my_config = {'__name__': 'foo', 'other_property': 'bar'}
mock.configure_mock(**my_config)
```

Again, depending what the purpose of your test double is, I'd suggest just using the simplest solution that achieves your goal.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
mock = MagicMock()
mock.configure_mock(name='my_name')
print(mock.name)
'my_name'
```

Comment: sorry i edit my code take a look you can find all what are you  looking for  in this doc https://python.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/library/unittest.mock.html